# pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'Can not find any timezone configuration' when I import aioxmpp

Tags: python-3.x, xmpp

I was thinking of giving aioxmpp a try. I successfully installed the library using pip.

But when I import it, it gives me

```
pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'Can not find any timezone configuration'
```

I then googled what the exception is and I don't see any connection between the pytz library and the the aioxmpp library. I tried everything, looking up pytz tutorials to set up a timezone but I can't find anything. Nor can I find any aioxmpp tutorials.

The usual code I start with is this

```
import aioxmpp

#Find out more about aioxmpp
results = dir(aioxmpp)

for result in results:
    print(results)
```

I even tried using the interpreter. It raises that exception as soon as I import the `aioxmpp` module.

Now, my question is, why is it raising that exception and how do I fix it? I literally just learned about `aioxmpp` a few days ago. I don't now where to start.

I don't know if it helps but I'm using an android app called PyDroid3 for programming.